# Find and replace values in matrix with the value from row 2

Tags: r, matrix, replace, row

I have a matrix with of 1's and 0's.  I want to replace all the 1's by an identifier code for that row (the identifier code is given in row 2)

I tried:

```
dax[,2:109] <- replace(dax[,2:109],dax[,2:109]==1,dax[2,])
```

but this isn't working right.  I've tried to set up a loop, but I've had no success so far.

I'm new to R.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: So, 1s and 0s to replace are from rows 3 onwards?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? What "isn't working right" about this?

Comment: Yes, Marc, the 1s and 0s are from row 3 onwards. Here is an example:

Comment: vector <- c(500,501, 502,999,866,878,101,0,1,102,0,1,103,1,1)  
    mymatrix <- matrix(vector, nrow=5 , ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)  
    mymatrix  

    mymatrix[,2:3] <- replace(mymatrix[,2:3],mymatrix[,2:3]==1,mymatrix[2,])  
    mymatrix

Comment: sorry about the formatting.  trying to figure out how to post my code of the reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do it for you, although it'd be nice to get more details from you.

```
for(j in 2:109) dax[dax[,j]==1,j] <- dax[2,j]
```